# How to make a table responsive, created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js, which generates a table for me, I show it in the html, but I can't make it responsive; how could i fix it

The code is the following, I have modified with responsive table, but it still does not work for me

```
var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
tabla.className="table";

var thead = document.createElement("thead");

let row_1 = document.createElement('tr'); 
let heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
heading_1.scope="col";
heading_1.innerHTML = "Mes";
let heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
heading_2.innerHTML = "Cuota";
heading_2.scope="col";
let heading_3 = document.createElement('th');
heading_3.innerHTML = "Interes";
heading_3.scope="col";
let heading_4 = document.createElement('th');
heading_4.innerHTML = "Amorti.";
heading_4.scope="col";
let heading_5 = document.createElement('th');
heading_5.innerHTML = "Capital";
heading_5.scope="col";
let heading_6 = document.createElement('th');
heading_6.innerHTML = "Seguro Desgrav.";
heading_6.scope="col";
let heading_7 = document.createElement('th');
heading_7.innerHTML = "Seguro Inmobil.";
heading_7.scope="col";

let heading_8 = document.createElement('th');
heading_8.innerHTML = "Gastos Adm.";
heading_8.scope="col";

let heading_9 = document.createElement('th');
heading_9.innerHTML = "Cuota Final";
heading_9.scope="col";



row_1.appendChild(heading_1);
row_1.appendChild(heading_2);
row_1.appendChild(heading_3);
row_1.appendChild(heading_4);
row_1.appendChild(heading_5);
row_1.appendChild(heading_6);
row_1.appendChild(heading_7);
row_1.appendChild(heading_8);
row_1.appendChild(heading_9);
thead.appendChild(row_1);
```

Comment: What does "responsive" mean, here? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the table in HTML.

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Then populate the fields in Js.

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](https://www.exeideas.com/2020/10/simple-responsive-html-table.html) if you are not using any of responsive CSS frameworks like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or my favourites (for the simplicity it offers) [W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tables.asp)